# fix money value going in minus

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a game in php in which people can upgrade their things the money would be deducted from their account. But when the money value becomes low, it goes in minus and the things are upgraded. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
</html>
<head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<?php echo "<font color=\"#49fb35\" size=\"5\">Update Firewall Software $300</font><br>"; ?>
<a href="firewall.php"><font color="#49fb35" size="5">Upgrade Firewall.exe for $300</font></a>
</head>
</html>
```

How to stop the upgrade if the money value is low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to verify that the value is more than 0, by using:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * from users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$result = mysql_query($query1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Get money from column
    $money = $row['money'];
}

if($money >= 300) {

$query = "UPDATE users SET firewall = firewall + 1, money = money - 300 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

} else {

// Prints error
echo 'Money is not enough to upgrade';

}
```

I'm not sure what variable name you are using, you can change accordingly, hope this helps!